# Gradle (2.3.9) mysteriously hates setting "version" to a number

Tags: java, gradle

I'm rather baffled on this. If I pass in this version number, gradle fails:

```
gradle -Pversion=120151021 build
:eventing:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':eventing:compile'.
> Could not find eventing-test.jar
```

I've no idea why it thinks it needs to find eventing-test.jar. That's the name I have it creating for the jar of test classes. Seems like a red herring of a message.

If I simply put ANY alpha character in front of the version string, it works:

```
gradle -Pversion=z120151021 build
:eventing:compileJava
:eventing:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:eventing:classes
etc
etc
```

It seems to be a problem if it just starts with numbers:

```
gradle -Pversion=11abc build
:eventing:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Though, in a truly bizarre turn, it's ok if it starts with a single "1":

```
gradle -Pversion=1abc build
```

I don't see anything in the Gradle documentation that says a numeric version number is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the original setup didn't work, but I worked around it as follows. Inside each jar and publish target, I specifically pulled in another variable as the version. For example.

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    version = System.getProperty('RELEASE_VERSION', "unversioned")
    appendix="test"
}
jar {
    version = System.getProperty('RELEASE_VERSION', "unversioned")
}
```

Note, it does NOT work to do this trick to set version at the outer gradle level. It results in the same error I had before.

**Does not work:**

```
apply plugin: 'application'
version = System.getProperty('RELEASE_VERSION', "unversioned")
...define tasks and such that would use "version" ...
```